# Segmentation fault MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have installed MySQLdb for python, and have the following code.

```
   import MySQLdb

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="hello")
```

Everytime I run this on terminal, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

But when I put the above lines in hi.py file, and run python hi.py, then I do not see this error in terminal.

Could anyone give me an advice to fix this problem?

```
$ python  
>>> import MySQLdb   
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="hello")      
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the command I typed in the terminal. And got segmentation fault error.

Comment: are you just trying to run it from the command line, as in: ./somefile.py?
if so, add #!/usr/bin/env python or something else that tells it how to run it.


Also, you need to fix your intending.

Comment: What do you mean by #!/usr/bin/env python ?

Comment: When I run the command from terminal, it gives the segmentation error. And when I put the command in python file, and run like python hi.py, then I do not see the error. So I want to know why the error is appearing when I  type commands in terminal.

Comment: you might want to post the entire command you run, with the result terminal output.

Comment: Edited in the original question.

Comment: @ToshihiroMSakurai : did you tried to compile/install MySQLdb manually instead of using a package manager ?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem before, try checking if you are using python2 with the terminal.

MySQLdb does not work with python3. If you want to work with python3 use `mysql-connector-python`

You can install it with `pip`: `pip install mysql-connector-python`