# How to troubleshoot Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)?

Tags: mysql, flask

I'm trying to use MySQL cursor to interact with remote database:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'sql7368254'  # it's a testing database. Nothing to exploit, really.
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'YnCZ8j4jbi'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'sql7.freemysqlhosting.net'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'sql7368254'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
db = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = db.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER, email VARCHAR(30), password VARCHAR(255))''')
    return 'Done'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I spin this off I get:

```
* Serving Flask app "server.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

"Segmentation fault" isn't telling me what is wrong. What might be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The import was a problem:

`from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112469/segmentation-fault-mysqldb) topic describes. Flask-MySQLdb doesn't work nicely with Python 3.
Using Python MySQL connector instead is advised.

Comment: Or the drop-in replacement `mysqlclient`.